# Twilio call duration

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

Is there a way to get info about call duration statistics via Taskrouter API?
I've been able to retrieve [TaskQueue Statistics](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/taskqueue-statistics) and [Worker Statistics](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/worker/statistics), but these don't include info about the average duration of a call.

I was thinking about using the `date_created` and `date_updated` timestamps of [reservations](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/worker-reservation?code-sample=code-read-reservation) with reservation status `accepted`, but that would include the waiting time for a reservation as well?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution based upon the `duration` property [see Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#linkcode)